# why is the effect size in sjstats anova_stats NA

Tags: r, mixed-model, effect-size

I am trying to find the effect size of my mixed effects model. I found `sjstats` provides several outputs including `eta-sq`, `omega-sq`, `cohen's f` and their partials. But when I run `anova_stats` on my model, the interaction term shows `NA`. For example,

```
 term             df    sumsq   meansq statistic    etasq partial.etasq  omegasq partial.omegasq cohens.f   power
 var1             1. 32.3     32.3      784.      0.479         0.931     0.428            0.581   3.67    0.382
 var2            1.  0.0190   0.0190     0.472   0.            0.00800  -0.0340          -0.124   0.0900  0.0510
 var1:var2       1.  2.39     2.39      58.1    NA            NA        NA               NA      NA      NA
```

Why do I have these `NA` terms? How do I fix it? Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Edit: summary() on the model

```
Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.3556 -0.5386  0.0327  0.5874  3.4658 

Random effects:
Groups             Name        Variance Std.Dev.
var1:var2:rand1 (Intercept) 0.002901 0.05386 
rand2           (Intercept) 0.013285 0.11526 
Residual                       0.041193 0.20296 
Number of obs: 3538, groups:  var1:var2:rand1, 3199; rand2, 36

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    4.252e-01  1.286e-01  3.256e+01   3.306  0.00231 ** 
var1         -1.495e-01  1.164e-02  2.828e+03 -12.849  < 2e-16 ***
var2         2.855e-02  4.135e-02  3.180e+01   0.691  0.49489    
...  
var1:var2  -1.229e-01  1.613e-02  2.799e+03  -7.623 3.38e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) var1  var2 var3 ...  varN
var1       -0.029                                                 
var2      -0.017  0.110                                          
...    
var1:var2  0.033 -0.721 -0.153  0.036  0.011  0.005 -0.010 -0.011
```

Comment: Hard to answer without more information. Can you show us the `summary()` of your fit? My best guess is that your model is overfitted in some way.

Comment: @BenBolker added the `summary()`.

Comment: OK, nothing obviously wrong (e.g. singular fits).  Any chance we can have a reproducible example ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker sorry I can't share the data.

Comment: if you can't share the data, and you want an answer (**maybe** someone with more knowledge or experience will have seen this phenomenon before, or be able to guess what's going on, but I wouldn't count on it), you need to come up with a set of made-up/simulated data that reproduces the phenomenon you're seeing.